# Zcat + awk with absolute path

Tags: linux, shell, awk, path, zcat

In my "test.tar.gz" there is a text file : "test.txt" with :

> *col1 {tab}   col2  {tab}  col3*

-

The problem is, when I run it :

```
zcat ./folder1/test.tar.gz | awk -F '\t' '{print $1, $3}'
```

It returns :

```
test.txt
```

So if I add :

```
zcat ./folder1/test.tar.gz | awk -F '\t' '{print $1, $3}' test.txt
```

It returns :

```
awk: cannot open test.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Thanks by advance !

Comment: However, if I go to my folder "folder1" and I run : 

    zcat test.tar.gz | awk -F '\t' '{print $1, $3}' test.txt

It works !

Comment: I'm willing to bet that there's a `test.txt` file in `folder1`.

Comment: Exactly @Wintermute haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
tar -xzOf test.tar.gz test.txt | awk '{print $1, $3}'
```

This extracts the file `test.txt` from the archive. The `-O` switch sends the contents of the file to standard output, which can then be piped to awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -xzf ./folder1/test.tar.gz test.txt -O | awk -F '\t' '{print $1, $3}'
```

Works perfectly. Thanks everybody !